# DP U.are.U bio-metric device with Android device from a web application

Tags: android, web-applications, biometrics, digital-persona-sdk

We have a web application which requires bio-metric authentication for users to login to the web application. Currently those users cannot login from Android devices because they cannot verify bio-metrics on their smart phones. We want to find a solution which will help our web application running on an Android device to authenticate our users using bio-metric device which will be connected using OTG cable.

We are currently using Java Applet for bio-metric verification on our desktop applications.
We know so far that we cannot open Java Applets on Android devices. So we will be willing to find another solution which will help us perform bio-metric authentication on both our desktop and Android devices.

Comment: You will have to code an Android App for your Biometric Authentication that points to the same Biometric database as with your web application.

Comment: How are you able to use a Java Applet on Web circa 2019? No modern web browser would support Java Applets as of this time. I am curious to know how you are doing that.